# Problems with display of UTF-8 encoded content from a DB

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding

Dear members of the Stackoverflow community,

We are developing a web application using the Zend Framework, and we are
facing some encoding issues that we hope you might help us solve. The
situation goes something like this: There are certain tables on a MySQL
database that need to be displayed as html. Because the site is designed
using the Spanish language, the database contains some characters like "á"
or "ñ". Our internal policy is to set all the encodings as UTF-8, including
all the databases and the tables. The problem is, that when we retrieve the
content from the DB, some characters are displayed as question marks.

We are out of ideas. These are all the things that we have already tried and
double-checked:
1. The SQL file from which we load all the data is properly UTF-8 encoded.
2. The SQL is loaded through phpmyadmin (which is configured as UTF-8), and
the resulting tables are displayed properly.
3. The netbeans environment used for coding is also set as UTF-8.

The weird thing is that all the content that is hard-coded either as php or
html is displayed properly. Only the values that are extracted from the
database have issues.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you use

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

in your config file like (application.ini)?

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to extract? CLI mysqldump OR phpmyadmin extract?

I had similar problems, even one time i extracted manualy (by coping DB with SELECT & INSERT).

Usualy this command solved problem `mysqldump --set-character-set=latin-1 --set-charset -u user -pPASSWORD databasename > databasename-latin1.sql`

Try also: http://www.saiweb.co.uk/mysql/converting-mysql-latin1-to-utf8

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right approach, but to fix this I just use a different document encoding when printing the latin characters from the database:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

I am certainly not sure why the UTF-8 encoding doesn't work. I am looking forward for the right answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection is set to utf-8 and just after you make a connection to the database issue the following sql

```
"SET NAMES 'utf8';"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify where encoding is get broken. I did not find clear answer on this in your post. You need to ensure:

1. Table encoding is properly set
2. DB Connection is configured properly (i.e. SET NAMES 'utf8' issued)
3. Zend views configured: resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
4. Apache configured right

Supposing all the above is checked, probably this would help. Add the following line to .htaccess:

```
addDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Tried everything but didn't work. The 3rd point i did it in the .ini file with the line: database.params.charset = "utf8". 
Is it correct?
Thanks my friend,

Answer (score 0):

I did had the same problem once ago  but i was using  these options

- Php 5.3
- PDO

turns out that pdo had bugs in PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND 
for example try :

```
try {
    $pdbo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

source : http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47224

hint : use Mysqli  its worked for me